# Toggle the Bloomberg real-time updates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, bloomberg

I'm using a BFXFORWARD() function to pull forwards for broken dates but they will only update if I turn on real-time updates and then refresh the workbook. If the workbook is not refreshed with real-time updates turned on, it gets stuck on "#N/A Requesting Data...". IT gets mad if I have the real time updates on for prolonged periods of time, so I'm trying to make a macro that turns real-time updates on, refreshes the workbook, pauses, then turns off real-time updates.

Function that needs updating:

`BFXFORWARD("USDJPY",TODAY()+30,"Askpoints")`

```
Sub testrefresh()
'
Application.Run "SuspendBloombergRealtimeData", True


Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorkbook"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Application.Run "SuspendBloombergRealtimeData", False
'
End Sub
```

I expected to see a checked box next to "Real-Time Updates" during the wait period but did not. Most importantly, the formula still resulted in "#N/A Requesting Data..." and did not change.

Comment: What/where is "SuspendBloombergRealtimeData" ?

Comment: Instead of turning real-time updates off, you could throttle the refresh rate to, say, 10 or 30 seconds. It's somewhere in the options of the add-in.

Comment: "SuspendBloombergRealtimeData" is supposed to toggle the Real-Time Updates in the Bloomberg tools tab. It does make everything in the sheet update live (prices are moving during market hours) but it is not reflected in the Bloomberg tools tab and does not allow the BFXFORWARD function to get past "#N/A Requesting Data..."